# how to render html code which is render from model in template as html

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i am creating a blog project for leaarning django right now i am wondering is it possible to write html code in model.textfield and when fetching it in my template it render as html code whole code as paragraph

let me exlain you with example i have model

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title  = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    urltitle = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=False, unique=True)
    info = models.TextField(blank=False,default=None)
    title_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='movies',blank=False, null=True)
    image_one = models.ImageField(upload_to='movies',blank=True, null=True)
    image_two = models.ImageField(upload_to='movies',blank=True, null=True)
    para_one = models.TextField(blank=True)
    written_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

as you can see in this model I have a text field name para one if I write code in that
like   Hello World  and save it then my template while rendering it it render hello world with h1 heading instead of like this Hello World as paragraph

i hope you got it or the or is there any way to do it or with any other field

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: https://github.com/django-cms/djangocms-snippet This can be used or you can use `https://ckeditor.com/ ` for this use-case as well

Comment: @NalinDobhal no i didn't tried anything yet right now i am looking fo a way to achieve that

Comment: @Blackranger you should atleast start, btw it is very much possible to store html in textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to render your textfield as html code you can use safe filter in your html file like this

```
{{movie.para_one|safe}}
```